# Angular 14 Hover not rendering in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html in a footer class where I need some chevrons:

```
<div class="link-list">
    <div *ngFor="let link of insideLinksLeft | originalOrderKeyValue" class="link">
        <a [href]="link.value" class="animated-link">{{link.key}} <i class="arrows-right fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need to happen is when I hover over the `animated link` the `arrows-right` need to move to the right. I have tried to do that here:

```
  .arrows-right {
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  .arrow-right:hover {
    right: 20px;
  }
```

I included the `arrows-right` class because I wanted to point out that that CSS is working properly. I believe the reason this isn't working is because the `<i>` tag is inside of an `<a>` tag, but I did that because I want the `<i>` tag to move to the right when I hover over the `<a>`. So if this isn't the best way to achieve this then please suggest a better way.

I have also tried this because the `<i>` is inside the `<a>` but it also didn't work

```
a.animated-link {
        color: #D1E2FF;

        &:hover {
          color: white;
        }
        &:hover .arrow-right {
          transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        }
      }
```

Here is the full CSS page to give you the full picture:

```
@import "/src/assets/style/variables";

@background-black: #4A4A4A;

.footer-wrap {
  width: 100%;

  .links-footer-wrap {
    padding: 50px 0;
    background: @background-black;

    .col {
      padding: 0 45px;
      border-left: 1px solid @border-gray;

      &:first-child {
        border: none;
        padding-left: 0;
      }

      .col-title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 28px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .link-list-wrap {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }

      .link {
        min-width: 205px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      a.animated-link {
        color: #D1E2FF;

        &:hover {
          color: white;
        }
        &:hover .arrow-right {
          transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        }
      }

      img {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
    }
  }

  .arrows-right {
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  .arrow-right:hover {
    right: 20px;
  }

  .privacy-footer-wrap {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    background: #F7F4EE;

    .privacy-footer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;

      .policy-link-wrap {
        width: 210px;

        .privacy-link {
          color: @link-blue;
          font-weight: bold;

          &:hover {
            color: @hover-blue;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the `i` a positioned element? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.arrows-right` is a child of `animated-link`, you can easily use:

```css
.animated-link:hover .arrows-right {
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<a class="animated-link"> Link <i class="arrows-right"> Arrow </i></a>
```